Import NodeSet2.xml file dynamically in OPC UA Server
I am a new to OPC UA Server development.
As per OPC Foundation SDK, I can build a OPC UA Server by loading the NodeSet2.XML and pre-generated codes files in development time. But I want that my application can load the NodeSet2.XML in run-time without changing my codes and compile again and provides the UA Information Model to the OPC Client to browse nodes.
Anyone can suggest that this can be possible by reading the NodeSet2.XML in run-time and provides the UA Information Model? If yes, can you suggest me where can I start.
I prefer in C++ language.

What exactly is the question? What have exactly have you tried? What is the error message? Try to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What do you gain by dynamically importing a nodeset? There won't be any useful functionality to it unless you write the code behind for reading, writing, method calls etc. And how can you write the code if you do not know the nodeset?

It depends on the used SDK (You wrote about C++, but the is the javascript SDK node-opcua). In case you use open62541, see this example from the docs:
https://github.com/open62541/open62541/tree/6fb959189261e072032f1c12ae91940394f60ca7/examples/nodeset_loader

I think you are using the C++ SDK from Unified Automation GmbH. The C++ SDK supports dynamic loading of the NodesetXML files using the method addModule().
Dynamic loading of NodesetXML
